# Add a field to the merge function view

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

How do I add fields to the view when merging records?

Answer (score 1):

All fields on the last used form are used for merge function, you don't have to do anything specifically other than making sure they are on the form.

The fields are always filtered and only shown if one or other of the merged records contains a value - this avoids wasting time and screen real estate asking users to select between two blanks, so they more easily see the fields that are different. Bit fields (two options) are included since they always have a value of 0 or 1.

See this page for some practical tips as well:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadcrmsupport/archive/2013/12/18/dynamics-crm-2011-merging-records-issue-with-multiple-forms.aspx